# jQuery-UI Dialog only showing last iteration of the for loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Don't know if I'm being blind but every time I look at this code the logic makes sense. I am trying to iterate through this for loop and for each iteration generate a dialog box with the ID of #dialog-(i) but it only show's the last iteration of 200. The code is below:

```
var i; 
    for(i=1;i<200;i++){
        $("#dialog-" + i).hide();
        $('#meetings_box-' + i).click(function() {
            var dialog = $("#dialog-" + i).dialog();
            if (dialog) {
                console.log('yay');
                console.log(dialog);
            } else {
                console.log('nay');
            }
        });
    };
```

Any help to finding the issue, probably something really dumb

Comment: I would suggest using callbacks. After each iteration you could call a show and on that dialogs callback you can iterate one higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `click` will happen sometime in the future and by then the loop has already finished it's execution and the value of i is updated to the last value. Instead of `var` you can use `let`

Comment: Cheers mate, this helped me figure out the issue